# What is the difference between "because" and "for"?

Tags: adverbs

Is there any substantial difference in the usage of "because"and "for"in a sentence/

Comment: As a native English speaker I don't see any similarity between current usage of "for" and "because". Could you give some examples where you have seen them used interchangeably?

Comment: I cannot tell whether she is old or young, for I have never seen her

Comment: Nice example, to my ears this seems rather archaic. I can imagine this in Pride and Prejudice, but not in common modern speech. However, I've just realised that one of my favourite songs "Who Know Where the Time Goes" uses "for" in this way.

Answer (score 2):

"because" is the normal and common conjunction for clauses indicating cause. Clauses 
with "because" follow after the main clause. Behind because is Latin causa meaning cause.
If the causal clause is before the main clause you use the conjunction as.

As causal clauses are used very frequently there are variants for "because". One variant is the conjunction for, in some dictionaries labelled literary/dated or simply formal. And sometimes ambiguous because "for" has a lot of uses.

- I cannot tell whether she is old or young, for I have never seen her. (Longman dictionary DCE). I derive this use of for from What for?